# Postgesql non-deterministic order of result with LIMIT and ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql

I understand that Postgresql may return results in non-deterministic order when the query parameters are non-unique. This is especially a problem when we use `LIMIT` since this may return entirely different results. So the suggestion for safety is to use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`.

However, what if we use `ORDER BY` on an non-unique column name? Will this produce a deterministic result or no? Let me demonstrate with an example:

We have the following data:

```
id | name | index
1    foo     5
1    bar     2
1    test    5
```

If I query `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY index LIMIT 1;`. Will this produce the same result every time?

Comment: Only a deterministic `ORDER BY` will produce a deterministic result. `ORDER BY index` is not deterministic.

Answer (score 2):

If there are multiple rows with the lowest value for `index`, then no, there is no guarantee you will always get the same row. If you only specify ordering for a column that contains duplicates, then the database does not have to provide anything more than any row that meets the criteria.

Same would be true if you were to say `ORDER BY index DESC` - which row with 5 would you expect? Why?

In order to force determinism / predictability, add a tie-breaker on a column that is unique (or at least unique within the same values of `index`). With your sample data, you could say:

```
ORDER BY index, name LIMIT 1;
```

But you haven’t shared enough about your table structure and constraints to get a more specific suggestion than that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that those earlier answers are correct.
Per the Postgres documentation on [Indexes and Order By](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html), Postgres with use the tuple identifier (TID), which is unique for each row, as a tie-breaker.

This was changed starting with v 12 of Postgres (or any version with BTREE_VERSION 4 indexes).